# How to make table of months from date to date?

Tags: php, html

I'm trying to make a table of years and months from date to date but I can't make it work like I want.

NOTE: dates will be dynamically changed in my app.

See the images below.

I get this:
[image]

But I want this
[image]

This is my code:

```
<?php

$start    = (new DateTime('2020-08-02'))->modify('first day of this month');
$end      = (new DateTime('2022-05-06'))->modify('first day of next month');
$interval = DateInterval::createFromDateString('1 month');
$period   = new DatePeriod($start, $interval, $end);

?>
<table border="1">
    <tr>
        <?php
        foreach ($period as $dt) {
            echo "<td>" . $dt->format("Y") . "</td>";
        }
        ?>
    </tr>
    <tr>
     <?php
        foreach ($period as $dt) {
            echo "<td>" . $dt->format("m") . "</td>";
        }
        ?>
    </tr>
</table>
```

UPDATED:
Now years and months works great, I have also added weeks to this table, but I have a problem with merging year row.

See the example how it looks like now
[image]

this is updated code:

```
<?php

include "db.php";

$date1 = '2020-11-02';
$date2 = '2021-03-06';
$start    = (new DateTime($date1))->modify('first day of this month');
$end      = (new DateTime($date2))->modify('first day of next month');
$interval = DateInterval::createFromDateString('1 month');
$period   = new DatePeriod($start, $interval, $end);


?>
<table border="1">
    <tr>
        <?php
        $d1 = date_parse_from_format("Y-m-d", $date1);
        $d2 = date_parse_from_format("Y-m-d", $date2);
        $f_val = 13 - $d1['month'];
        $s_val = $d2['month'];
        $ar = array();
        $ar1 = array();
        $th_span = array($f_val, 12, $s_val);
        $i = 0;
        foreach ($period as $dt) {
            $ar += array($dt->format("Y") => 0);
            $ar1 += array($dt->format("m") => 0);
        }
        foreach ($ar as $k => $v) {
            $number = 0;
            foreach ($ar1 as $k1 => $v1) {
                $q = $con->prepare("SELECT COUNT(id) AS total FROM nedelje WHERE godina=? AND mesec=?");
                $q->bind_param("ii", $k, $k1);
                $q->execute();
                $r = $q->get_result();
                $v = $r->fetch_assoc();
                $num = $v['total'];

                $number = $number + $num;
            }

            $num1 = $th_span[$i];
            $number1 = (int)$num1 * $number;
            echo "<th colspan=" . $number1 . ">" . $k . "</th>";
            
            $i++;
            
        }

        ?>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <?php
        foreach ($period as $dt) {
            $month = $dt->format("m");
            $year = $dt->format("Y");

            $q = $con->prepare("SELECT COUNT(id) AS total FROM nedelje WHERE godina=? AND mesec=?");
            $q->bind_param("ii", $year, $month);
            $q->execute();
            $r = $q->get_result();
            $v = $r->fetch_assoc();
            $number = $v['total'];

            echo "<td colspan=" . $number . ">" . $dt->format("F") . "</td>";
        }
        ?>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <?php
        foreach ($period as $dt) {
            $mesec = $dt->format("m");
            $godina = $dt->format("Y");

            $sql = $con->prepare("SELECT nedelja FROM nedelje WHERE godina=? AND mesec=?");
            $sql->bind_param("ii", $godina, $mesec);
            $sql->execute();
            $res = $sql->get_result();
            while ($row = $res->fetch_assoc()) {
                echo "<td>Week " . $row['nedelja'] . "</td>";
            }
        }
        ?>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe there is another simple way.
But this one is working fine for me. To eliminate duplicate values, I created a new array called $ar and stored all year values as key in it. This will help to eliminate all duplicate values.

```
<?php
$date1 = '2020-08-02';
$date2 ='2022-05-06';
$start    = (new DateTime($date1))->modify('first day of this month');
$end      = (new DateTime($date2))->modify('first day of next month');
$interval = DateInterval::createFromDateString('1 month');
$period   = new DatePeriod($start, $interval, $end);

?>
<table border="1">
    <tr>
        <?php
        $d1 = date_parse_from_format("Y-m-d",$date1);
        $d2 = date_parse_from_format("Y-m-d",$date2);
        $f_val = 13-$d1['month'];
        $s_val = $d2['month'];
        $ar = array();
        $th_span = array($f_val,12,$s_val);
        $i = 0;
        foreach ($period as $dt) {
             $ar += array($dt->format("Y") => 0);
        }
        foreach($ar as $k => $v) {
            echo "<th colspan=".$th_span[$i].">" . $k . "</th>";
            $i++;
         }
        ?>
    </tr>
    <tr>
     <?php
        foreach ($period as $dt) {
            echo "<td>" . $dt->format("F") . "</td>";
        }
        ?>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: I know that, but I don't want duplicates of year, I want to merge cells

Comment: I have updated my code. Please check and let me know if you have any trouble

Comment: I have tried your code, there is no duplicates now, but there is still the main problem. How to merge cells. For example: 2020 needs to be merged from august to december... then start 2021.

Comment: I have updated the code and this time I also checked the HTML part.

Comment: There was a small mistake, I corrected it now. Please note that this code only works this given date range. In this line $th_span = array(5,12,5); the number shows how many months merge in each heading year respectively. If you don't want to use table heading you can change this <th> into <td>

Comment: I see, now it works perfectly. But is there a way to make this to be dynamic. For example these two dates won't be the same every time. Maybe second date is "2023-06-10". Is there a way to make something like that?

Comment: I have updated the code. Now check and let me know if you have any further queries.

Comment: Thanks, this worked perfectly. I have added update to my question, I have added also weeks from my database, and only need to merge year cells to looks fine. Could you check my code

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code:

```
    function addMonth(strDate, strDateEnd, count)
{
     var d = new Date(strDate);
     if(d == 'Invalid Date') return 'BAD DATE!';
     
     d = new Date(strDateEnd);
     if(d == 'Invalid Date') return 'BAD END DATE!';
     
    
     const param = strDate.trim().split('-');
     var   year  = parseInt(param[0]);
     var   month = parseInt(param[1]);
     var   day   = parseInt(param[2]);
     
     const param1= strDate.trim().split('-');
     var   e_year  = parseInt(param1[0]);
     var   e_month = parseInt(param1[1]);
     var   e_day   = parseInt(param1[2]);
     
     for(var c=0; c<count; c++)
     {
        month++;
        if(month == 13)
        {
            month = 1;
            year++;
        }                        
        strDate = year + "-" + month + "-" + day;             
        
        if(e_year < year) break;
        if(e_year == year && e_month > month) break;
        if(e_year == year && e_month == month && e_day > day) break;
    }
    
    var is29D = false;
         
    if( year % 4 === 0 ) is29D = true;
    if( year % 100 === 0 && year % 400 === 0 )  { is29D = true; }    
        
    
    if(month == 2 && day > 28 && !is29D) { day = 28;  }    
    if(month == 2 && day > 29 && is29D ) {   day = 29; }        
    if( day > 30 &&  ( month == 4 || month == 6 || month == 9 || month == 11 )  )  { day = 30; }                
                        
     
    if(month < 10) month = '0'+month;
    if(day < 10)   day = '0'+day;
     
    return year + "-" + month + "-" + day;
}
```